# What do we call it when everything—pitch, chords progression, etc.—changes in a song?

Tags: terminology, songwriting, production

There is a technique that I don't understand in some songs where everything changes—the pitch drop, the chord progression, the melody, etc. The only thing that stays the same is the vibe. Here are some examples:

What is this technique, and how is it used?

Comment: In the first example, it is patently false that "the vibe stays the same." I would call that section the bridge, and sometimes the bridge goes to a different key.

Comment: If "everything" shifts but the song seems to stay the same then it may have been subjected to a modulation.  Some pieces do this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two examples it is really just a sudden key change.

In *The Weeknd - I Was Never There feat. Gesaffelstein* It changes from A minor to F minor.

While for the last example it is indeed used a electronic technique of sound pitchshifting (there the pitch is shifted to form a descending minor triad arpeggio) that then leads to a key change.

About "the vibe" staying the same one should say that this is very subjective. For me each of the 3 key changes coincide with structural changes in the songs.

Answer (score -1):

Modulation is when the key 'pivots' as different keys can share a few chords. For example suppose the song is in the key of C (CFG,Dm,Am,B°) and when it hits an F chord it then switches to chords in F (F, G, A, B♭, C, D).

Key shift is everything moving up or down ... a song perhaps in C moves up to G in the last verse (The Beatles - Penny Lane, comes to mind).